# Android Revolution HD on GT-N8010 wifi won't turn on

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1

I just flashed the Android Revolution HD rom on my Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 (GT-N8010). My device was in 4.1.2 and now is on 4.4.2. I seem to have one big problem: After pressing the wifi toggle slider it looks as if it would turn on but immediately goes back to off.

I've checked that the rom I used is the right one. So, what would be the cause of this? And more importantly, how could I solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Schlotty.

Link to the ROM thread: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2119547

Comment: Tried other ROMs? Also, since ARHD is a stock-based ROM, it's possible you'll need to be on the latest stock ROM before flashing it, so as to make sure the baseband, etc. are up-to-date.

Comment: Yep, after trying with a couple of roms and a little reaserch I came to the conclusion that i would first need to be on 4.4.2 in order to flash ARHD. Problem is, my carrier hasnt recieved a kit kat ota update, so... The only thing that seems reasonable is to first flash a stock KK rom from a different carrier and then flash ARHD. Does that make sense? Would it be possible to flash a stock rom from a different carrier on my device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ARHD is a stock-based ROM, it's possible you'll need to be on the latest stock ROM before flashing it, so as to make sure the baseband, etc. are up-to-date.

In case your carrier doesn't offer a 4.4.2 update, find them on [SamMobile](https://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/galaxy-note-101/GT-N8010/) and download one for your generic region, or another carrier in the region, so as to get the right set of language (not all languages are available in all firmwares). Making sure the model number matches is the only other thing you need to do. Back up your data, then flash the update with Odin. After booting up the new stock OS, flash the recovery and then ARHD once again.